# asp.net Problems when I access my database

Tags: asp.net

I'm having this problem when I launch my website and try to access my database:

> Oops. The error: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

I have a database and I'm connecting to it(Part of the code I used is):

```
 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con;
            con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS; AttachDbFilename=C:\\inetpub\\poject\\App_Data\\data.mdf; Integrated Security = true; Connect Timeout = 30; User Instance = True";
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

Is the path right?  Did you misspell "project"?

Comment: I've not connected to a DB using AttachDbFilename, so I'm really just guessing here.

Comment: @Mickey No, you are right.  He shouldn't get that message and, if that's his code, it would help if "project" was spelled correctly.

Comment: I know "project" is misspelled but this is how i spelled in my path. IS their any other way to connect to the database as this way is nt working?

Answer (score 0):

What I do to make sure that I don't have any syntax errors is open server explorer and connect to my SQL Server that way.  Then, when I click on the particular connection under "Data Connections" in server explorer, there is a Connection String property associated with each Connection.  I just copy and paste that to avoid any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this Steps.

1. Make sure you have Sql Management Studio Express : [Sql management studio express 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=08e52ac2-1d62-45f6-9a4a-4b76a8564a2b)
2. Attached your Database Data.mdf
3. Then change your connection string to this on your web.config file.  Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Data;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True

Regards